# Visual Studio 2012 Layer Diagram

Tags: visual-studio-2012, data-modeling

I'm quite a fan of the modelling tools in VS, and over the last couple of months, i've been facing humm let's call it a color context issue. OK let's be more specific, let's say im using a layer diagram, i drag a layer box onto the canvas, and it's default colour is blue, 161| 199| 231.

But when you save it, close the diagram and re-open it, it becomes white! The color turns to 238| 238| 253.

And this happens to the other symbols as well, such as the comment box, the dependency arrow as well...

Anyone facing a similar issue ? I initially thought an update would have fix that, or perhaps its some issues with VisualSVN integration.. dunno. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just find out that it's also happening with VS2010 :(